# How to optimize a join?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, query-optimization

I have a query to join the tables. How do I optimize to run it faster?

```
val q = """
          | select a.value as viewedid,b.other as otherids
          | from bm.distinct_viewed_2610 a, bm.tets_2610 b
          | where FIND_IN_SET(a.value, b.other) != 0 and a.value in (
          |   select value from bm.distinct_viewed_2610)
          |""".stripMargin
val rows = hiveCtx.sql(q).repartition(100)
```

Table descriptions:

```
hive> desc distinct_viewed_2610;
OK
value                   string

hive> desc tets_2610;
OK
id                      int                                         
other                   string
```

the data looks like this:

```
hive> select * from distinct_viewed_2610 limit 5;
OK
1033346511
1033419148
1033641547
1033663265
1033830989
```

and

```
hive> select * from tets_2610 limit 2;
OK

1033759023
103973207,1013425393,1013812066,1014099507,1014295173,1014432476,1014620707,1014710175,1014776981,1014817307,1023740250,1031023907,1031188043,1031445197
```

`distinct_viewed_2610` table has 1.1 million records and i am trying to get similar id's for that from table tets_2610 which has 200 000 rows by splitting second column.

for 100 000 records it is taking 8.5 hrs to complete the job with two machines
one with 16 gb ram and 16 cores 
second with 8 gb ram and 8 cores.

Is there a way to optimize the query?

[image: spark-executor pic]

Comment: Partition your tables (if possible), use ORC or Parquet for better file formats, adjust your memory settings so that you can fit the smaller joined table into memory (if possible), etc... Typically how you squeeze Spark performance. Question is: How many executors are you running? What settings did you give to them? Is there skew in your data that made one executor take a long time?

Comment: Thanks for the reply..Need clarifications on below point..1. I read from few documents that spark will not check in which format the data has been stored it directly access the data from the path.My queries on ORC and non-ORC table proved that as the response times seems to be the same?

Comment: Where did you read that? Of course Spark cares about data format. If you make a Dataset, then a columnar data format will be most optimal than a plain text file.

Comment: I have 4 executors and have just attached the snapshot of my executors tab which gives the info regarding to the memory allocation

Comment: Well, at first glance, you are only using 12 cores on the larger machine, and 4 on the other. I'm guessing 4 cores are being allocated for something else. If you want more executors, you can set 1 or 2 cores. Also it doesn't look like the memory is really being used at all.

Comment: Also, why are you not using something along the lines of `SELECT * from  bm.distinct_viewed_2610 a JOIN bm.tets_2610 b ON a.value = b.value`? I don't see the need for this `FIND_IN_SET(a.value, b.other) != 0 and a.value in` business, but the nested query will not be performant.

Comment: in this case..it used my all my executors,fine.but in few cases it uses only few executors and making nore time to execute..is there a  command to make the query use our executors effectively

Comment: It's an exercise up to you to write better SQL. The SparkSQL parser and optimizer determine how executors are allocated and data is distributed. The only "commands" you can give are memory configurations for the jobs.

Comment: the join command what you have mentioned wil not work out,because a.value is not equal to b.id,in my case my a.value is a part of b.others..so i have used the UDF FIND_IN_SET.Please let me know if i have clarified properly

Comment: I didn't write `b.id`. The fact that you are testing `a.value in (select value from bm.distinct_viewed_2610)` to me says that you should do an equijoin on those values rather than a nested query

Comment: there is no common column to equi join the tables

Comment: If that is true, then you are wasting 8 hours trying to find where `a.value = b.value`

Comment: Sorry,I got your point now ..I will limit my query  until this and wil check the performance select a.value as viewedid,b.other as otherids from bm.distinct_viewed_2610 a,bm.tets_2610 b where FIND_IN_SET(a.value,b.other)!=0

Comment: You are still doing a cartesian join. I promise you that doing a proper SQL `JOIN` will be better

Comment: More information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538225/how-does-select-from-two-tables-separated-by-a-comma-work-select-from-t1-t2

Answer (score 0):

Now you are doing cartesian join. Cartesian join gives you 1.1M*200K = 220 billion rows. After Cartesian join it filtered by `where FIND_IN_SET(a.value, b.other) != 0`

Analyze your data.
If 'other' string contains 10 elements in average then exploding it will give you 2.2M rows in table b. And if suppose only 1/10 of rows will join then you will have 2.2M/10=220K rows because of INNER JOIN.

If these assumptions are correct then exploding array and join will perform better than Cartesian join+filter.

```
select distinct a.value as viewedid, b.otherids
  from bm.distinct_viewed_2610 a
       inner join (select e.otherid, b.other as otherids 
                     from bm.tets_2610 b
                          lateral view explode (split(b.other ,',')) e as otherid
                  )b on a.value=b.otherid
```

And you do not need this :

```
and a.value in (select value from bm.distinct_viewed_2610)
```

Sorry I cannot test query, do it yourself please.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using orc formate change to parquet as per your data i woud say choose range partition.

Choose proper parallization to execute fast.

I have answred on follwing link may be help you.

[Spark doing exchange of partitions already correctly distributed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951207/spark-doing-exchange-of-partitions-already-correctly-distributed/46958771#46958771)

Also please read it

http://dev.sortable.com/spark-repartition/